# Choosing the right parameters for a Pulse wave simulation in a CAD schematic

Tags: amplifier, pulse, ads

I'm trying to choose the right parameters in the simulation in order for the output to show a square wave of gain C1/C2 = 2V

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The inverting input is not referenced to any DC voltage therefore it floats. It needs to have negative feedback via a resistor to keep it centred between the power rails. My recommendation is to use a feedback resistor (maybe 10 kohm) and also add a 10 kohm in series with C1. Make C1 a lot higher in value too.

The circuit I propose would have a gain of 1 and will remove the DC offset from the input signal. That is what I believe you are looking for. An op-amp's gain cannot be adequately defined purely by the ratio of capacitors.

Comment: Are time, period and those parameters correct too? Becuase that's also giving me problems

Comment: @tadm123 you have inadequately defined requirements and an op-amp circuit that cannot work as shown. I'm trying to help you find a solution. The circuit I proposed has a ggain of 1 and removes the DC offset (as would your circuit due to C1). Apart from that I have no idea what your aims are. If you can elaborate please do so. An op-amp with a bandwidth of 100 MHz will not be useful for the signal frequency you are proposing BTW.

Comment: Well I'm trying to plug in any parameters to simply make the amplifier work but I need to design it in this manner (two capacitors). It's not really a very sophisticated design or very complete, just a simple example of an amplifier with two capacitors. Any values whatsoever will do really as long as it works..

Comment: For example I tried doing the simulation with a Sinusoid signal and it works. But I just simply need to do the same but with a pulse (or square) signal, but I ran into problems. https://postimg.cc/image/8oy75gr4b/  https://postimg.cc/image/uo4lso08r/

Comment: I'm completely sure the problem is with putting wrong values on the transient and square signal settings.

Comment: Let me state this again - an opamp NEEDS proper DC biasing at both inputs. You don't get that without using resistors despite what your simulator tells you. It WON'T work without resistors.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips. Here is the new design https://postimg.cc/image/v7ivthbkr/ https://postimg.cc/image/bpo8dj6x7/  I'm still getting this weird output

Comment: Please show the new circuit. Also try running it with a much lower frequency to see what happens  - try 10 kHz. I'm off-line for several hours now so won't be able to respond. Did you set the BW to be massively higher than 100 MHz? It's impractical of course but if you want a near-square wave output at 100 MHz you'll need a bandwidth greater than 10 GHz.